# How to flatmap a stream of streams in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to transform the stream of streams of objects to a single stream of objects. I know that I have to use the `flatMap` method, but I'm not able to achieve that, look at:

```
Stream<Stream<Object>> objectStreams = ...
Stream<Object> flatMappedStream = objectStreams.flatMap( ... );
```

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Basically, you want to concatenate all the nested streams into one flat stream, without affecting the members themselves. You'll use

```
objectStreams.flatMap(Function.identity());
```

because you must provide *some* mapping function for each stream member, and in this case it is the identity function.

---

Usually we end up with the nested streams because we apply a function that maps an item to a stream:

```
Stream<Stream<Object>> objectStreams = srcStream.map(itemToStreamFunction);
```

If this is your case, just change `map` to `flatMap`:

```
Stream<Object> flatMappedStream = srcStream.flatMap(itemToStreamFunction);
```